# Please identify these sub assemblies

Tags: set-identification

I got these assemblies and I am trying to figure out if they are MOCs or part of a set or sets.  The little figure that has the clown inside has a part with a decal of "spirit of luis",  but this only appears in 7307 so it might be a MOC.  What about the rest.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The wing and red cockpit are from  [9497-1: Republic Striker-class Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/9497-1/Republic-Striker-class-Starfighter)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The little build in the bottom left corner is part of set [8897 Jagged Jaws Reef](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8897-1).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I found by accident that the bike is the [2259 
Skull Motorbike](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2259-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), but partially built and modified.
[image]